# change inner key in multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace, key

I want to ask about how to replace inner key in a multidimensional array.
I have an multidimensional array :

```
$array1=
array(array(5000, 6,  325,  3,  3,  517000000),
      array( 20000,  5,  217,  5,  3,  1692000000)
      );
```

The second array is

```
$array2=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

I expected the new array is

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [1] => 5000
        [2] => 6
        [3] => 325
        [4] => 3
        [5] => 3
        [6] => 517000000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 20000
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 217
        [4] => 5
        [5] => 3
        [6] => 1692000000
    ))
```

I have tried this code below by another post [PHP Replace multidimensional array keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556151/php-replace-multidimensional-array-keys), but I can't assign the value of my array1

```
foreach($array2 as $array2 ){
    for($k=0;$k<sizeof($array2);$k++){
        for($l=0;$l<$count;$l++){
        $last[$l][$array2] = $array1[$k][$l];
    }
    $i += $count;
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Look at `array_map()` and `array_combine()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rizier has suggested in his comment you can do this using array_map() and  array_combine().

```
<?php
$array1=
array(array(5000, 6,  325,  3,  3,  517000000),
      array( 20000,  5,  217,  5,  3,  1692000000)
      );
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

foreach($array1 as $arr1){
    $array3[] = array_combine($array2, $arr1);
}
var_dump($array3);
```

output

```
  array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          1 => int 5000
          2 => int 6
          3 => int 325
          4 => int 3
          5 => int 3
          6 => int 517000000
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          1 => int 20000
          2 => int 5
          3 => int 217
          4 => int 5
          5 => int 3
          6 => int 1692000000
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
$array1=
array(array(5000, 6,  325,  3,  3,  517000000),
      array( 20000,  5,  217,  5,  3,  1692000000)
      );
$newArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $arr){
  array_unshift($arr,'');
  unset($arr[0]);
  $newArray[] = $arr;   
}

print_r($newArray);
```

this will have same output you require.
hope it helps :)